# Add Custom Button to TinyMCE in Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, tinymce, components

I am currently creating a component for Joomla 2.5.

I would like to add a custom button to the TinyMCE editor, but being in the context of a Joomla component, I can not add files or code inside the TinyMCE editor plugin...

Is someone able to tell me what I am suppose to use to do so?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editor buttons are built as `editors-xtd` plugins. You may look at the `readmore` button, which is only added in article context.

Comment: That's definitely the preferred approach, that way the button is available in all editors not just TinyMCE. You don't know what editor (if any) that your users may be using.

Comment: I looked at the file `editors-xtd/article/article.php` , and indeed this seems to be the right way to solve my problem. But this Class return a `$button` object, so what I am suppose to do with it in order to add it to my editor ?

Comment: Nothing but making an `editors-xtd` plugin and activate it. Joomla does the rest.